# Getting string for an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm getting the results of an array using this

```
$arrayResults = $_GET;

$arr = $arrayResults;
```

and am then using this to get the variables:

```
foreach ($arr['seller'] as $seller) { 
  echo $seller;
}
```

which out puts **value 1 value 2 value 3** but when I put that into a MySQL query it doesn't work so I need to get them into a string and ideally have something like this - **"value 1" OR "value 2" OR "value 3"**

This is the query I'm using

```
$sql_select = "SELECT * "; 
$sql_from = "from feeds,product_categories_map where feeds.seller =".dbstr( $seller )." and feeds.enabled=1 and feeds.stock=1 and feeds.deleted=0 and feeds.best_seller=1 and product_id=product_feed_id and product_feed_id!=1 ";
$sql_orderby = " ORDER BY rand()";
$sql_limit = " LIMIT 20";

    $query=$sql_select . $sql_from . $sql_group . $sql_orderby . $sql_limit;
    $product_results=dbselect( $query,"dbLinkInt" );
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: _I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here_ You are concatenate an array  with a string

Comment: How do I fix that, sorry I'm very new to php - this is the firs time I've used it

Comment: Construct part of the query inside your foreach loop and then use it. However, you've got a massive security issue here known as MySQL injection and you should look into what prepared statements are as this code is not suitable for production

Comment: Please dont do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql_select = "SELECT * "; 
$sql_from = "from feeds,product_categories_map where feeds.seller =".dbstr( $seller )." and feeds.enabled=1 and feeds.stock=1 and feeds.deleted=0 and feeds.best_seller=1 and product_id=product_feed_id and product_feed_id!=1 ";
$sql_orderby = " ORDER BY rand()";
$sql_limit = " LIMIT 20";




$query = "SELECT * from feeds,product_categories_map where feeds.seller=%s and feeds.enabled=1 and feeds.stock=1 and feeds.deleted=0 and feeds.best_seller=1 and product_id=product_feed_id and product_feed_id!=1 ORDER BY rand()";

$query = sprintf($query, mysql_real_escape_string(dbstr($seller)) );
```

Please use sprintf method and mysql_real_escape_string.
sprintf on its own will not protect you.
Also you may look at an OO design.

All the best

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you've **sanitize your input**, you should just format your variable this way

```
$seller = implode("','", $arrayResults); //this format the array into comma separated string
```

Then change your query to:

```
$sql_from = "from feeds,product_categories_map where feeds.seller IN ('".$seller."') and feeds.enabled=1 and feeds.stock=1 and feeds.deleted=0 and feeds.best_seller=1 and product_id=product_feed_id and product_feed_id!=1 ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to consist of two parts, and gives rise to a third issue:

**1. Joining a number of array elements into a single string**

PHP's [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function allows joining the elements of a given array with a given string.

For example:

```
$seller = array('value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3');
$seller_joined = "\"" . implode("\" OR \"", $seller) . "\"";
echo $seller_joined ;
```

Should echo:

```
"value 1" OR "value 2" OR "value 3"
```

**2. Writing an SQL WHERE clause which checks whether a certain attribute equals one of a certain set of values**

If you want to check whether a certain attribute equals one of a number of possible values, you should use the SQL [IN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator, and separate the values by a comma instead of the keyword OR, e.g.:

```
$seller_joined = "\"" . implode("\", \"", $seller) . "\"";
$sql_from = "from feeds,product_categories_map where feeds.seller IN (". $seller_joined .") and feeds.enabled=1 and feeds.stock=1 and feeds.deleted=0 and feeds.best_seller=1 and product_id=product_feed_id and product_feed_id!=1 ";
```

**3. Sanitizing input to the database**

As suggested by the following answers, you should make sure you [sanitize your strings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) before you pass them to the database, in order to prevent [SQL injection](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/10/how-security-flaws-work-sql-injection/).